# pnp-js Unable to update file in subsite 403 error

Tags: spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, pnpjs

I am trying to update a file in document library from webpart, code is working fine for site collection but not working for subsite, getting below error message

```
Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [403]  ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied."}}}
```

I am using pnp js, here is the code I am using

```
          const file = await _sp.web.getFileByUrl(fileUrl);
          try {
            await file.setContent(fileContent);
          } catch (error) {
          }
```

Getting error in file.setContent

_sp is initialized in webpart's oninit method

```
public async onInit(): Promise<void> {
    
    await super.onInit();
    getSP(this.context);
  }
```

getSP is coming from config file

```
var _sp: SPFI = null;

export const getSP = (context?: WebPartContext): SPFI => {
  if (_sp === null && context != null) {
    //You must add the @pnp/logging package to include the PnPLogging behavior it is no longer a peer dependency
    // The LogLevel set's at what level a message will be written to the console
    _sp = spfi().using(SPFx(context)).using(PnPLogging(LogLevel.Warning));
  }
  return _sp;
};
```

file url is comin from query string.

Webpart is added to a page in site colection, which tries to read/set file content to a file in subsite.

Comment: It seems you don't have access on library in subsite

Comment: @RajatSahani its admin user with full control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the root cause and fix the issue, root cause was I was using root web object to try updating a file in subsite, I have to use subsite web object, here is the fix I have used:

```
      try {
            await file.setContent(fileContent); //update the file content
            }
          } catch (error) {
            try {
              console.log(error);
            console.log("trying new approach");
            const web = Web([_sp.web, siteURL]); //Initiate new web object, existing web will not work for subsite 
            const file2 = await web.getFileByUrl(fileUrl);
            await file2.setContent(fileContent);
            } catch (error) {
              alert(error);
            }            
          }
```

siteURL is the subsite's absolute url coming from querystring